# 4 values in an array with sum = x

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, analysis

I don't need the code for this. I was wondering if someone could show how to find 4 integers in an array of size n that could equal a value x in time complexity n^2logn. I tried looking for videos but found them hard to follow. From my understanding you create a helper array of all the possible pairs? Sort them and then find a sum of x from the smaller arrays?

Eg. Array = { 1,3,4,5,6,9,4}
Can someone very explain in steps how to check for a sum of say 8. Just need help **visualizing** this process.

Comment: Why not O(n^2)? Put the sums of all `n (n - 1) / 2` pairs in a map, then iterate over the keys (sums) of the map and see if `target - key` exists as a key in the map (and that the list elements, which are the values stored for the sums-as-keys in the map, don't overlap).

Comment: Really nice [גלעד-ברקן](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2034787/גלעד-ברקן)! One minor note, map/dict in general has a logarithmic insert or at least lookup time. So overall we need O(n^2 log n) time and quadratic space.

Comment: If you search in your browser for "target sum problem", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 0):

```py
# your input array 'df' and the sought sum 'x' 
df = [1,3,4,5,6,9,4]
x = 12

def findSumOfFour(df, x):
    # create the dictionary of all pairs key (as sum of a pair) value (pair of indices of 'df') 
    myDict = { (df[i]+df[j]):[i,j]  for i in range(0,len(df)) for j in range(i,len(df)) if not i == j}

    # verify if 'x' - a key 'k' is again a key in the dictionary 'myDict',
    # if so we only need to verify that the indices differ
    for k in myDict.keys():
       if x-k in myDict.keys() and not set(myDict[k]) & set(myDict[x-k]):
           return [df[myDict[k][0]],df[myDict[k][1]],df[myDict[x-k][0]],df[myDict[x-k][1]]]

    return []

solution = findSumOfFour(df,x)
print(solution)
```

Note, this approach follows the description of [גלעד-ברקן](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2034787/%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%93-%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%A7%D7%9F) (comments) explained with more detail and on your example.

Note 2, the runtime is in O(n^2 log n) since the insert and lookup operations in a map/dictionary in general is O(log n).

Comment: Thank you for your notice, I corrected my mistakes.